# The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation v3 and v4 you must set up your app container directly

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Im trying to outline the navigator but getting the navigation prop is missing error.
Ive added all packages needed, following a tutorial from The Net Ninja 
its also imported successfully btw import Home from './screens/home'; has blanked out

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Home from './screens/home';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import Navigator from './routes/homestack';


const getFonts = () => Font.loadAsync({
    'Lacquer-regular': require('./assets/fonts/Lacquer-Regular.ttf'),
    'Roboto-bold': require('./assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf')
  });



export default function App() {
const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if(fontsLoaded){
  return (
   <Navigator />
  );
} else {
  return (
  <AppLoading 
    startAsync={getFonts}
    onFinish={()=> setFontsLoaded(true)}
  />
  )
   }
}
```

How my routes look like I am using V4 of react-navigation :

```
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import About from '../screens/about';

const screens = {
    About: {
        screen: About,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'About HorrorZone',
        }
    },
}

const AboutStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' }
    }
});

export default AboutStack;
```

How the Homestack file looks like if its any help:

```
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Home from '../screens/home';
import ReviewDetails from '../screens/reviewDetails';

const screens = {
    Homepage: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'HorrorZone',
        }
    },
    ReviewDetails: {
        screen: ReviewDetails,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Review Details',
        }
    } 
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator (screens, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' }
    }
});

export default HomeStack;
```

This is the exact error i get:

[image: Error]

Comment: Can you please post code of your `./routes/homestack` file ?

Comment: i added my homestack

Comment: I uploaded my answer. Please check. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Navigation V3, you are required to use the container directly. In V3 **createNavigationContainer** renamed to **createAppContainer**.

Example for V3

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
```

If you are using React Navigation V4, navigators have been moved to a separate repository. You will need to install and import from 'react-navigation-stack'.

Example for V4

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
```

There are lot of breaking changes happened to React Navigation in different versions. Please have a look.

https://reactnavigation.org/blog/#breaking-changes

Comment: I am using V4 and i am using import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack' still getting the error

Comment: then please update your description that you import and initiated navigation properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have not wrapped your stack navigator into app navigator. Please wrap your `HomeStack` in `createAppContainer` and then export it like this :

```js
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; // import this
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Home from '../screens/home';
import ReviewDetails from '../screens/reviewDetails';

const screens = {
  Homepage: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'HorrorZone',
    }
  },
  ReviewDetails: {
    screen: ReviewDetails,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Review Details',
    }
  }
}

// store stack navigator in any variable
const stack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'red' }
  }
});

// create app container 
const HomeStack = createAppContainer(stack);

export default HomeStack;
```

Made same changes in your `AboutStack`.

**Note:** It is not good to use appContainer more then one in your navigator. Instead of just create one router which wrap up your all stack navigator in one appContainer.